# jQuery, disappearing element

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lastinput").click(function() {
    $("#blank").html("text to display");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="blank"> </div>
  <div id="login">
    <form>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="eg. yourname@gmail.com" id="email"><br>

      <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="eg. 123456789" id="phone"><br>

      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password"><br><br>

      <input id="lastinput" type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a problem with display element named id = "blank" browser show it on 0.1 second and then disappear,
I search for solution for one day and still cannot find mistake
Thank's for help in advance.

Comment: The reason is because when you click the `#lastinput` element it submits the form causing the page to unload as it redirects. This is standard behaviour.

Comment: Probably because you're submitting an empty form when you click on `#lastinput` - add a `return false` to the end of your function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your submit button is inside a form, so once you submit that form, it expects a url to be returned to redirect to. As you haven't supplied one, it redirects to a blank page.

You need to either remove the submit button from the form or turn the form into an Ajax form to submit the information and update the page without refreshing it:

```
$("#lastinput").click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url here',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#blank").html("text to display");
        },
        success: function() {},
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it usual for people to downvote and not give reasons why so I can't improve my answer?